# Two identical USB drives auto-mount with different owner group permissons, but why?

Tags: usb, mount, automount

**UPDATE:** (solved- sort of}  See my *answer* below

---

I have 2 identical USB drives which I've both formatted to identical specs using Gparted. Both have two identical primary partitions (ext4 and ntfs).

- I have not created any mount-point directories for them.
  (An afterthougt: actually I did, but deleted them, so there are none now.
   and I did manually mount them (as a test)... Maybe(?) this has **done** something(?)
   but there are now no "created-by-me" directories in /media, for these USB drives)
- There is no mention of them in /etc/fstab.

I want them to auto-mount, and I'd expect them to mount identically...
...but for some reason, the **ext4** partitions are mounting with different **permissions** and different **group**.

As can be expected with *root:root* ownership, and *no write permission* for *group/other*, it is causing my rsync backup to fail (for usb2).

What might be causing these different mount settings?... (I'm using 10.04)

```
rsync: failed to set times on "/media/usb2ext4/.": Operation not permitted (1)  
rsync: recv_generator: mkdir "/media/usb2ext4/.Trash-1000" failed: Permission denied (13)  
Skipping any contents from this failed directory
```

---

```
usb1: 'sudo fdisk -l' -and- 'ls -l /media'  
==========================================
     Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System  
  /dev/sdd1               1      108547   871903746   83  Linux  
  /dev/sdd2          108548      121601   104856255    7  HPFS/NTFS  

  drwxrwxr-x 31 root fred 4096 2010-12-17 15:30 usb1ext4  
  drwx------  1 fred fred 4096 2010-12-16 14:04 usb1ntfs  

usb2: 'sudo fdisk -l' -and- 'ls -l /media'  
==========================================  
     Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System  
  /dev/sde1               1      108547   871903746   83  Linux  
  /dev/sde2          108548      121601   104856255    7  HPFS/NTFS  

  drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 2010-12-17 10:19 usb2ext4  
  drwx------  1 fred fred 4096 2010-12-16 14:04 usb2ntfs
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved! (sort of...)

... I've been doing some very deliberate and detailed tests for several hours now (including manually mounting the drives, as well as the auto-mount), and always with the same results.. Repeatable reslults!... **until** I tried something which shouldn't make a difference, but it did!

... I simply plugged in the "problem" drive on its own, and it mounted perfectly (on its own)! .. okay, so I then plugged in the other drive and it too mounted perfectly! ... I've subsequently rebooted, plugged, unplugged, and mounted, and unmounted (via Nautilus).. and all is working fine now

... There's nothing quite like a good mystery!  ...( and OMG! I certainly have learnt a lot about mounting tonight! ... It was worth it alll, just for that :)